# C++ - Overloading of operators needed for an iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm trying to create an iterator on a library that allows reading a specific file format.

From the docs, to read the file content you need do something like this:

```
CKMCFile database;

if (!database.OpenForListing(path)) {
  std::cerr << "ERROR: unable to open " << path << std::endl;
}

CKMCFileInfo info;
database.Info(info);

CKmerAPI kmer(info.kmer_length);

uint32 cnt;
std::vector<uint64_t> data;
std::vector<uint64> ulong_kmer;
data.reserve(info.total_kmers);

while (database.ReadNextKmer(kmer, cnt)) {
  kmer.to_long(ulong_kmer);
  data.push_back(ulong_kmer[0]);
}
```

Now, I started with this class `wrapper`:

```
class FileWrapper {
  CKMCFile database;
  CKMCFileInfo info;
  Iterator _end;

  public:
    explicit FileWrapper(const std::string &path) {
      if (!database.OpenForListing(path)) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: unable to open " << path << std::endl;
      }

      database.Info(info);
    }

    Iterator begin() {
      Iterator it;
      it.database = &database;
      it.total = 0;

      uint32_t cnt;
      std::vector<uint64_t> ulong_kmer;

      CKmerAPI tmp(info.kmer_length);
      database.ReadNextKmer(tmp, cnt);
      tmp.to_long(ulong_kmer);

      return it;
    }
    
    Iterator end() const { return _end; }
    uint64_t size() { return info.total_kmers; }
};
```

And then, this is the `Iterator` class:

```
class Iterator {
    friend class FileWrapper;

    CKMCFileInfo info;
    CKMCFile *database;
    uint64_t kmer, total;
    
    public:
      Iterator &operator++() {
        ++total;

        uint32_t cnt;
        std::vector<uint64_t> ulong_kmer;

        CKmerAPI tmp(info.kmer_length);
        database->ReadNextKmer(tmp, cnt);
        tmp.to_long(ulong_kmer);

        return *this;
      }

      bool operator<(const Iterator &rhs) const { return total < rhs.total; }
      uint64_t operator*() const { return kmer; }
  };
```

But, during some test I can't use into a `for loop` for something like `for (auto it = begin(); it != end(); ++i) { ... }` or `begin() + size()`. How can I overload correctly this two operatos? `opeartor!=` and `operato+`

Comment: You have possible worse problems that build errors: You forget to initialize `total`, which will lead to *undefined behavior* when you use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A compile time, for now I have this error: `error: no match for 'operator!='`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to think about 2 major things before:

1. Ownership. Currently, you have to make sure your `FileWrapper` survives at least as long as any `Iterator` returned from it by calling its `begin()` (since your `Iterator`s store pointers to data owned by the `FileWrapper` object). If you cannot guarantee that, maybe think about using `unique_ptr`s or `shared_ptr`s
2. Iterator Category. As discussed in the comments, it appears that your database requires you to use "[input iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)". They can only be incremented by one (do not provide `operator+(int)`) and dereferenced. Indeed, what would the iterator `begin() + 10` look like? If this should advance your file-pointer, then you **cannot** define the end as `begin() + size()` as that would just skip through the file.
3. Representation. What should an end-iterator look like? A simple choice might be to indicate the end with `database == nullptr`. In this case, an `operator!=` might look like this:

```c++
bool is_end() const { return database == nullptr; }

bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const {
  if(is_end()) return other.is_end();
  if(other.is_end()) return false;
  return (database == other.database) && (total == other.total);
}

bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { return !operator==(other); }
```

Now, you'll need code that ensures that all end-iterators have `database == nullptr` and, whenever a non-end iterator becomes and end-iterator by application of `operator++()`, you'll need to set `database = nullptr` and `total = 0` (or something).

A note at the end: your `Iterator`s may be in an inconsistent state after construction and before assignment of their `database` member. It is prudent to declare a proper constructor for `Iterator` that initializes its members.

EDIT: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hMYesffT5)'s a suggestion for an integration

Comment: And the `operator+` how can I define that?  I don't need the `end()` iterator, `end() = first() + size()`

Comment: that depends on how you want to use it. When you simply define `operator+=(size_t x)` to call `operator++` x times, then your file-pointer will have advanced and any other iterator (or copy of that iterator made previously) will be off. So, indeed, for file-data, I would always use ForwardIterators only (that is, only provide `++`, but not `+`), not RandomAccess iterators (who provide `++` and `+`)

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man: You're making a pure input iterator. You shouldn't give it `operator+`.

Comment: @igel: Since the database object seems to internally store the position, it can't be a ForwardIterator (forward iterators *must* provide multi-pass, and this doesn't seem feasible here).

Comment: The library only support `forward_iterator`. The best thing for me is could scan the file only with the `begin()` interator and the total elements of the file (`total_kmers`). How can I do that with my code integrated with your?

Comment: @NicolBolas you're right, I should have said "InputIterator", it's my bad

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man: "*The library only support forward_iterator.*" Then you're out of luck. Your API *cannot* provide the behavior of a ForwardIterator; whatever this "database" thing is, it does not (at least from the information we've been given) support having a position. It always reads first to last, and can never store the current position or reset it. If the interface you're trying to use requires a multipass iterator, and your database system can't do multipass, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man: You will have to read the data into a container of some sort in its entirety, then present that container to whatever code will consume it.

Comment: Why you said "Your API cannot provide the behavior of a ForwardIterator" ?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It would be possible to have a caching iterator that used reference counting or so to decide when to free data from the underlying input iterator (equivalent); then if the iterator usage is “mostly” single-pass the memory consumption would be lower than the eager container approach.  That of course might or might not matter enough to justify the implementation/maintenance burden.

Comment: @igel The snippet in your example fall into `segmentation fault`

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man I'm not surprised as it's only a concept, really. Without any knowledge about the CKMC-classes (and how you use the code) there's really not much I can do to correct that.

Comment: @igel Thank you, your suggestions was precieuses. I was able to implement correctly the classes